# Where to put the callback?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

```
db.listCollections().toArray(function(err, collections){
    for(i = 1; i < collections.length; i++){
        if(i < parseInt(collections.length)){
                   var collect = db.collection(collections[i].name.toString(),function(){
                    collect.count(function(err,result){
                      console.log(collections[i].name.toString());
                        corrCount = corrCount + result;
                    });
                });
            }else{
                collect = collections[i].name;
        }
    }
});
```

So my problem is that `collect` ends up being undefined and thus one can't count the amount of entries in the collection. Something tells me that I should solve this with callback but I keep failing. Also I don't understand why the console prints out 2 times before it shots of the error. I'm using nodejs with mongodb native driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move the rest of the code out of the callback, like so:

```
db.listCollections().toArray(function(err, collections) {
    for (i = 1; i < collections.length; i++) {
        if (i < parseInt(collections.length)) {
            var collect = db.collection(collections[i].name.toString());
            collect.count(function(err, result) {
                console.log(collections[i].name.toString());
                corrCount = corrCount + result;
            });
        } else {
            collect = collections[i].name;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Seems to work, which is kinda wierd that's what I had before :/. The problem now is that I want to use corrCount in the else block but when I do console.log(corrCount) it prints 0 when it should be 1. I guess there is some way to make the else wait for the if block to return values?

Thank you for the help by the way!

Comment: So you're basically just trying to do something for the last collection in the count? If so, you can move the if \ else block into the callback

Comment: Also, you would probably want to initialize i at 0 and not at 1, since array's first element is always 0

Comment: I have about 7 collections and I want to sum the counts of the first 6 collections then I want to save the count of the last collection so I get 2 variables.


Started i at 1 because you get system.indexes at index 0.

Comment: In this case you would probably have to use recursion or [async](https://github.com/caolan/async), since you want to waterfall asynchronous tasks

Comment: I will try. Your answer solved the question that I posted so i'll accept.